# Video lectures about Information Theory and Thermodynamics!

Tags: reference-request

I'd like to know if there is any video courses that relate information theory and thermodynamics, e.g. courses cover laws of thermodynamics, Shannon's entropy, Kolomogorov Complexity, Landauer’s Principle, and anything related to them in one course.

Thank you!